# NativeScript - how to decrement application icon badge number for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, notifications, nativescript

Using Nativescript I want to be able to decrement the icon badge number when specific actions are done in the app.

I've started with this code (example):

```
if (app.ios) {
  app.getNativeApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5;
}
```

I've read that for iOS 10+ I need to get an authorization from the `UNUserNotificationCenter`. I tried using an app delegate when the app starts to ask for the authorization and it doesn't seem like I can have access to the authorization class from Nativescript.

I tried looking for plugins and can't seem to find any ...

If anyone knows how I could access the Authorization api or even deal with icon badge update from NativeScript it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [nativescript-local-notifications](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications#requestpermission) for requesting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress, in my `AppDelegate` I updated to:

```
        appDelegate.prototype.applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = function (application, launchOptions) {
            var center = coreUtils.ios.getter(UNUserNotificationCenter, UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter);
            center.delegate = this; 
            const authorizationOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge;
            center.requestAuthorizationWithOptionsCompletionHandler(authorizationOptions, (granted, error) => {
                if(!error) {
                    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5;
                } else {
                    console.log("Error", error);
                }
            });
```

Now the problem is that when I open the app, the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` gets set to 0. I was able to test that by putting an event listener on the `applicationDidEnterBackground` event and setting `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to 5. I was then able to see the badge icon. Now I have to figure out why the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` gets set to 0 on app open.

Comment: I believe you are targeting iOS 10 and above. By any chance if you are planning for iOS 9 support which is default target in {N} projects, this might not work. At least you will have to verify the version before running this code at runtime.

Comment: @Manoj, sure thing I’ll take care of making sure it works on prior iOS versions. I was able to make the badge appear. I’m just wondering why it’s set to 0 when the app opens. Don’t know if it’s the normal Nativescript behaviour.